# getting error during aerospike GET "read tcp *.*.*.*:39068-> *.*.*.*:3000: i/o timeout " in golang

Tags: go, tcp, aerospike

I am getting error from aerospike during GET operation as

> read tcp CLIENT_IP:39068->AEROSPIKE_IP:3000: i/o timeout

https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/master/types/result_code.go

Interesting point is, in aerospike codebase there is no error related to `i/o timeout`.

*is this error means my golang client is not able to connect to aerospike cluster ?*

PS: for security reasons i have masked client IP as **CLIENT_IP** and aerospike cluster IP as **AEROSPIKE_IP**

Comment: i have used default read policy (BasePolicy) except Timeout and MaxRetries(Timeout set to 500 ms and MaxRetries set to 1)

Comment: Are you able to connect to the aerospike cluster from aerospike tools running on same client machine. (ie asinfo -v build -h IP_address

Comment: Also may need try to tweak https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/f20d63ae09793eafed462f89e977b11b7c52b5e6/client_policy.go#L55 (ConnectionQueueSize,IdleTimeout )

Comment: thanks @ivolmar for the reply, current we use default ConnectionQueueSize,IdleTimeout , can you pls guide what are the ideal values of this ,does this varies depending upon the throughput which it handles ?

Comment: hi @ilolmar, i was using a old version of kafka, after going throught this https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/issues/227 thread,i updated kafka to newer version and errors have reduced to zero , thanks